# Add attribute in child element of dynamic HTML

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am getting HTML from server api and in that HTML I want to add `target="_blank"` to an anchor coming inside a div. I want to do that at front-end due to some restrictions, So please let me know how to do this.

I tried the following approach but I didn't like it as it is a SPA and it can have other elements with this class name.

1. `componentDidMount() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('download_div')[0]
         .getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
         .setAttribute('target', '_blank')
    }`
2. I can also use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)`. But accessing the DOM node and manipulating is against the React style. So I didn't go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to find the element that needs the additional attribute and use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to output the results.

For instance:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const apiHtml = fetch('/my_api').then((apiHtml) => { 
    // fetch the raw HTML you want
    this.setState({apiHtml})
  })
}

render() {
  const rawHtml = this.state.apiHtml.replace('<a href', "<a target='_blank' href")
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.apiHtml && <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rawHtml}} />}
    </div>

  )
}
```

Alternatively, a more complex approach would be to parse and transform the HTML string using [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)

```
import ReactHtmlParser, { processNodes, convertNodeToElement, htmlparser2 } from 'react-html-parser';

function transform(node) {
  if (node.type === 'a' &&) {
    return convertNodeToElement(node, index, transform); // Alter the object here to suit your needs
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Right now I am also doing the same dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: content.replace(/<a href/g, '<a target="_blank" href')
                  }} But is this the right approach as it will check the complete html to find the macth and will add target to all the links. I was looking for some React way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think if you may want to parse the HTML and then loop over the results creating React-controlled elements and create them yourself. For instance https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser has a 'transform' method that should do what you need.

Comment: It seems that second approach is the only available react style to achieve it so I am accepting your answer. But for others Please let us know if there is any way to do it without using any other dependency.